# How do I get Windows 10 to "Update, restart and go to sleep"?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, sleep

When I'm done working, I always put my Windows 10 PC into "Sleep" mode rather than shutting it down, since waking from sleep mode is faster than booting. I guess a lot of people do this.

Now, when Windows Updates are pending, I get the following options:
[image: shutdown options]

Obviously, for people who prefer sleep to shutdown, the most useful option would be "Update, restart and then go to sleep". I could click on it, go home, and tomorrow, when I return to my PC, it (a) has been updated and (b) starts fast.

Unfortunately, this obviously useful option is missing. Workarounds are (1) click "Update and restart", play with my smart phone for some minutes, and then put the PC to sleep, (2) click "Update and shut down" and accept that I will have to wait the next time I urgently need my PC or (3) click "Update and restart", go home, and waste 30 minutes of power until the PC automatically goes to sleep. All of these are unsatisfying.

**Is it possible to perform "Update, restart and then go to sleep" using Windows 10 builtins** (for example, by issuing some clever command-line command)?

Comment: To be honest, it really isn't that surprising.  You are the first person I have ever seen request this specific option.  Everyone else that I know either doesn't really have any problem with needing to fully power-up their machine *once or twice per month* after they install Windows Updates, **or** they don't think it is overtly problematic to have the PC on for an extra 30 minutes twice each month after a post-install reboot before it sleeps.

Comment: @Run5k: Fair point (I removed the "surprising" part), and now that I think about it, determining *when exactly* the boot (and possibly automatic login) process is finished and the PC should be put to sleep is probably a highly non-trivial task. Still, smarter people than I frequent Superuser, some of them are perfectionist when it comes to personal productivity, and maybe one of them already found a solution for this issue.

Comment: You could write a script that sends a computer to sleep after a few minutes, then write another script that places this script in RunOnce and restarts the computer for updates. Triggering the second script would reboot the computer to complete updates and then on subsequent power on the second script would be run and sleep the computer.

Comment: @music2myear +1 This is exactly what I'd expect a Super User to do to save a few seconds on login time. I've spent 2 hours perfecting scripts that don't save me more than 10 seconds each time I use them.

Comment: @music2myear: Yes, that would be the obvious way to implement it. However, before doing that, I wanted to check if (a) someone else already did it or (b) there is a simpler way (such as some hidden `shutdown` switch or some smart Powershell one-liner). Hence, my question here.

Comment: It is very unlikely there is a "restart for updates and then sleep" command built into the OS. While you use the words "obviously useful" and other turns of phrase that make us believe that you consider this to be a widely needed action, the fact that to several of us seasons IT pros this is the first we've ever heard of such a need/request/desire indicates that it is not a particularly wide need. Someone may have already done it, in which case you should be searching Google, but that would be a software request here on Super User.

Comment: While this might be a nice capability to have, are the default options *really* that problematic? If it genuinely is a serious issue to *"waste 30 minutes of power until the PC automatically goes to sleep,"* it sounds like the root cause of the problem is more budgetary than technical. On the other hand, if the machine is shut down after Windows updates and you might *"urgently need"* the PC when you arrive in the morning, remember that [Windows 10 Fast Startup mode](https://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/) is on by default. Can it wait 70 seconds?

Comment: @Run5k: No, it's not really that problematic. It's a minor annoyance and often there are simple, but less well-known solutions to minor annoyances. *"No, there's no easy/built-in way to do that without some serious scripting."* would be a perfectly fine answer. Oh, and "power wasting" is more cultural than budgetary: We Europeans have all been brainwashed to avoid "wasting power" whenever possible. ;-)

Comment: I came here via Google, looking for the same thing, because with 'Off' instead of 'Sleep' I can't use wake on WLAN, and because my PC often runs things without a user, I can't have it go to sleep on its own.

Comment: An easy workaround is to change energy settings to sleep automatically after a very small time like 2 minutes, then choose "update and restart", then computer restarts, so when it's powered up again by the restart it waits 2 minutes and then it sleeps. So It wouldn't waste almost any energy extra except 2 more minutes. When you get the computer back you should remember somehow to turn the sleep to what it was before modifying it.